# getting same URL when uploading to firebase storage - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Whenever I'm trying to upload a file to firebase storage, and then retrieve the download URL for it, I'm getting the same URL even when different files are uploaded. The files do get uploaded, but the URL received is similar for every upload

```
downloadURL = new Uri[1];
    UploadTask uploadTask = mChatPhotosStorageReference
            .child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment())
            .putFile(selectedImageUri);
    Log.v("SelectedImage: ", selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

    uploadTask
            .continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful())
                        throw task.getException();
                    return mChatPhotosStorageReference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            })
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        downloadURL[0] = task.getResult();

                        //passing downloadUri to database to store with chat messages
                        ShutUpMessages shutUpMessages = new ShutUpMessages(null, mUsername, downloadURL[0].toString());
                        mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(shutUpMessages);
                        mProgressbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mProgressbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
```

Comment: The whole `downloadURL[0] = ...` smells fishy. What happens if you simply do `new ShutUpMessages(null, mUsername, task.getResult().toString()`? And after you uploaded some images, can you edit the question to show the JSON at `mMessagesDatabaseReference`. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Do not see the mistake. But as I was doing kindof a similar thing the other day I would suggest you to store just the reference path and not the Uri. This saves you an access to the dB and still gives you the same result in requesting. If you do not need the Uri somewhere else, this would be enough